# MVC 4 deployed to IIS 8 Page can't be Displayed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to deploy a MVC 4 application to IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012.
I am copying the files to the server by using Publish > File System.
I have created a new web site in IIS on the server, pointed this to the correct directory, but when trying to view the site I see '**This page can’t be displayed**'.

I have never deployed an MVC application before, so may have missed something very simple.

After spending a lot of time searching on the Web, I have:

- Ensured the correct version of .NET (4.0) is installed, and is selected   within a new Application Pool created specifically for my app
- Disabled Directory Browsing
- Ensured the System.Web.MVC.dll is copied into the Bin folder
- Added the following to web.config:

Below:

```
 <modules>
     <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
     <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

I am very grateful for any help or suggestions!

Martin

Comment: Have you checked Windows Event logs? Are there any errors logged there?

Comment: No errors in Event Viewer!

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear...it looks like the problem was caused by my using Port 110 in the web site bindings. I think this is a reserved Port.

Hope some of the bullets above help someone else anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's usually used by POP3 email. Everything up to 1024 has an officially registered use, but some have multiple and then there are plenty of _unofficially_ in use ports beyond that. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) has a good list. It's worth noting that you can use the ports for other things (as long as there's not something else listening on those ports), but it's not recommended.